# Is Memcache secure for multiple sites and one memcached instance?

Tags: php, wordpress, memcached

I'm setting up a server which will be hosting multiple websites, some, or perhaps all of which would benefit from memcached.  If I have them all using the same memcached instance, isn't that a security concern?  Couldn't one site over-write another's cache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That seems to be correct.  If you want to have multiple applications (such as a website) all using memcached, then you need to have separate instances of memcached running.  Memcached is simply a key->value store, and has no separation of users/permissions/etc.

One way you can do this easily is with https://gist.github.com/lboynton/3775818 or a similar memcached init script, and then set up each instance to use a unix socket in a place that only that site's user has access to (this is much easier to set up if each site is running as a separate php-fpm instance, say).

Answer (score 0):

Not a problem if you have control over the cache keys. Just prefix the keys with a unique identifier for each site. That way they cannot overwrite each others caches.

However, you may not have that detailed control over the cache keys. In that case I would go with several instances of memcached. That is probably safest and easier to scale aswell.

Comment: Yeah - I'd thought of that.  As long as any instance *doesn't* have control over whether or not they use the prefix, you're OK.  So if there was a memcached middleman which automatically added the prefix... but if not, then technically one could over-write the other.  Memcached has a keys dump function (stat cachedump) which could be user to figure out other users' prefixes.